# JSF error on deploying ear file on WebLogic 12

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, weblogic12c, nosuchmethoderror

Am using Weblogic 12.2.1.4 and on deploying my ear file am getting the following error. My ear is done with JSF 2.2.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V
        at org.primefaces.util.Jsf23Helper.addSearchKeywordResolvers(Jsf23Helper.java:27)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PostConstructApplicationEventListener.java:48)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:704)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:270)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:719)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:191)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1929)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3191)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1864)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:919)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method "addSearchKeywordResolver" is part of JSF 2.3 specification. https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver.html

Therefore, if you want to use it, you will have to include the dependencies for JSF 2.3 in your ear file.

Answer (score 1):

This method is called by PrimeFaces, if it recognizes that its running on JSF2.3.
If this method is then not available, you probably have duplicate dependencies in your classpath (or something like 2.3 API and 2.2 impl)